# Handling the click on a SearchView's icon

Tags: android, android-toolbar, searchview

First, I will explain to you what I want to do. Then, I will show you what I've already done. Finally, I will ask for your help about what I will implement.

## My aim

My aim is to have a `Toolbar` like the Playstore: [image]

When you click on the burger menu, it displays the menu.
When you click on the input, it displays changes the icon and it displays keyboard:

[image]

## What I have for now

[image]

I followed the documentation (https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/ + https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog + https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup). Thus, I have:

1. `res/menu/action_bar_menu.xml` containing my `SearchView` widget

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:title="@string/search_title"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

2. A `Toolbar` in my fragment's layout:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorRoyalRed"
    android:theme="@style/ToolbarStyle"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

3. The style `ToolbarStyle` (see above):

```
<style name="ToolbarStyle">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorRoyalRed</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorRichYellow</item>
    <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/ToolbarActionButton</item>
</style>
<style name="ToolbarActionButton">
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingStart">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingEnd">0dp</item>
</style>
```

4. In the fragment class, I make use of the toolbar:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("");
    AppCompatActivity app_compat_activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
    Objects.requireNonNull(app_compat_activity).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    app_compat_activity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);

    return view;
}
```

5. In the fragment class, I make use of the `SearchView`:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater menu_inflater) {
        menu_inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar_menu, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,menu_inflater);

        AppCompatActivity app_compat_activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();


SearchView search_view = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.searchView).getActionView();
        search_view.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        SearchManager search_manager = (SearchManager) Objects.requireNonNull(app_compat_activity).getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        search_view.setSearchableInfo(Objects.requireNonNull(search_manager).getSearchableInfo(app_compat_activity.getComponentName()));
    }
```

Well, there are other implementations (modifications concerning the manifest, etc.) but they are not important (note all the required changements to implement a simple search bar in the toolbar... more than 5 steps...).

## What I would want to do next (help please!)

**I don't want to use anything other than the menu items structure (thus I don't want to actually add the `SearchView` in the fragment's layout).**

1. How could I change the `SearchView`'s icon? For now it's a magnifying glass. It must be a burger menu. I tried to modify `res/menu/action_bar_menu.xml` by indicating a `android:icon=` to the `SearchView` but it didn't work. I also tried to use `<item name="searchIcon">@drawable/ic_baseline_menu_24px</item>` in the style `ToolbarActionButton` but it didn't work. **Here the aim is to replace the glass by a burger menu icon.**
2. How could I handle the click on the `SearchView`'s burger menu icon (once it will be set)? Indeed, I will call my `DrawerLayout::openDrawer` function to open my menu.
3. How could I handle the click on the `SearchView`'s content? Indeed, I will replace the burger menu by the left arrow (and, if clicked, keyboard will disapear and the burger menu will be displayed).

## Am I using the wrong things?

I just followed Google's documentation. But it seems so complicated to me to realize that I may be on the wrong path? Should I stop using the menu items structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try [SearchEditTextLayout](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Dialer/+/android-n-preview-4/src/com/android/dialer/widget/SearchEditTextLayout.java) available under this Google project - 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Dialer/

These libraries may also help you to achieve your desired results.

[SearchView](https://github.com/lapism/SearchBar-SearchView) and [FloatingSearchView](https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview)

Comment: Note that lapism's `SearchView` seems to bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52432965/infinite-ui-loop-lapism-searchviews-text-query-bar-click-always-and-systematic